# Solution for our menu

Tags: routes, blocks

I have this scenario:
- We have domain access to show different content by location including menus
- we have one top menu to show different "home pages" where the user could target information. Home 1, home2, home 3, etc...
- we have a main menu for each "home page".
- we have 3 type of content that can have a lateral menu and even the same lateral menu for those 3. This lateral menu has 3 levels. and those content types could be linked in every one.
- a node of content type 1 for example, could be referenced many times in the lateral menus.

[image: example menu]

We need some help with this issue. We are considering the menu block and/or NodeSymlinks, and/or multiple node menu modules.

Could you advice us ? regards.

Comment: so, you haven't actually tried anything yet? despite the fact that you know of at least 3 potential options?  why haven't you tried them?

Comment: The option we already have is a custom made dev. But we have a lot of issues with that option. Our problem now it that we have the deadline really close and we need some advice. I've tested the menu block., the other two options are only to link the same node to a diferent menu item, but im not sure if it is "compatible" with menu block. I was wondering if someone have solved an issue like this to see if the way im looing is wrong or to see if there is another alternative.

Comment: oh ok, that makes more sense now. Sorry I have no experience with that, just found the question odd

Comment: If you can just avoid the menu duplicates then menu_block module can do this. Just have duplicate content instead of duplicate menu items.